# onclick checkbox + ajax cache html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having an issue with the following (an old system I'm updating):

- I have a checkbox list in a `<div id='list'>`.
- When a checkbox JS clicked, an ajax request is called that return JS to execute.
- This JS in the Ajax request gets `'#list'` to cache the html so we can redisplay in few other places.

Problem: 
The html cached is always being prior to the checkbox value instead of after

The html code:

```
<div id="list">
  <input id="checkboxRessource_413" type="checkbox" onclick="throwXMLHttpRequest('modif.php','', '4', '413','',  'contributeurUpdate');">name 1
  <br>
  <input id="checkboxRessource_414" type="checkbox" onclick="throwXMLHttpRequest('modif.php','', '4', '414','',  'contributeurUpdate');">name 2
</div>
```

The ajax file returns the following javascript:

```
var htmlList = $("#list").html();
```

The problem is `htmlList` contains html Prior to the checkbox being checked, how can I get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of jQuery you are using, the `onclick` event will fire and process before the value of the checkbox has actually changed. I would suggest using an `onchange` event instead of `onclick`, as this will ensure that the event will not run until after the checkbox has checked or unchecked.

Additionally, `$.html()` will not return the status of the checkbox. The actual html in the DOM does not get altered whenever you check the box; the `checked` status is stored as a `property` on the input, as opposed to an `attributed`. You'll need to manually check the `checked` status of each checkbox and send that information to your .php page. See example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xH83D/) here.

```
var checkedStatus = []; // send this array to your php
$(':input', '#list').each(function () {
    checkedStatus.push($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```